# I am not used in prepared statement mysql and i am new in OOP php daskite

Tags: php, oop, prepared-statement

I want to return the value of u,p,d in my index.php but i don't know what to code in return

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT u,p,d FROM pump_price");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($u,$p,$d);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // what to return here?
}
$stmt->close();
$this->mysqli->close();
```

Comment: There is no need for the `prepare/execute`, you're not using an actual prepared statement. Using `query()` will suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bind_result()` function should make available the values of `u`, `p`, and `d` in the variables `$u`, `$p`, and `$d`, for each record in the result set.  So you may try the following:

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT u, p, d FROM pump_price");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($u,$p,$d);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "(" . $u . ", " . $p . ", " . $d . ")" . "\n";
}
$stmt->close();
$this->mysqli->close();
```